# Parsing different numbers with RegEx

Tags: python, regex, email

Is it possible to parse all of the "weights" from the two emails below?

I need a RegEx powerful enough to capture **only** the "weights" from these two emails, and 100's of more emails. The RegEx I'm using now searches for commas and takes the numbers on either side of them, which is perfect for weights in the thousands, but fails to capture weights below one thousand, such as the 954lbs and 800lbs values below.

I have thought maybe I could possibly try to recognize "lbs" and capture the number preceding that, but in some cases the price precedes "lbs".

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

```
1) Subject: FW: NEFS 11 fish for lease
   From: Claire Fitz-Gerald 
   Date: 11/15/2013 3:02 PM

   NEFS 11 has the following fish for lease:

   -GOM Cod up to 5,000 lbs (live wt) @ 1.40 lbs
   -American Plaice 2,000 lbs      .60 lbs or best offer



2) From: Claire Fitz-Gerald 
   Date: 9/5/2014 9:52 AM
   Subject: NEFS 5 Available Fish

   All,
   NEFS 5 has the following fish available for lease/trade:

     GB EAST cod: 954 lbs @ $0.83
     GB EAST cod: 1,046 lbs to trade for 1,830 lbs GB WEST cod
     GB blackback: 30,000 lbs @ $0.07
     GOM blackback: 800 lbs @ $0.03
     white hake: 6,322 lbs @ $0.13
     pollock: 22,000 lbs @ $0.015
     redfish: 14,000 lbs @ $0.015
     GB yt: 1,873 lbs @ $1.13
     GB yt: 5,127 lbs to trade for 10,254 lbs SNE yt
```

My relevant code:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            pattern = re.compile(r'\d+,\d+ ')
            email = f.read()
            weights = pattern.findall(email)
            data_frame['Weights'].append(weights)
            if weights:
                print("Weight:", ''.join(weights))
```

Printout, for email #2: (notice the amounts that are less than 1000 are excluded)

```
Weight: 1,046 1,830 30,000 6,322 22,000 14,000 1,873 5,127 10,254
```

Comment: I don't see the `'lbs'` in your pattern, but anyway you can allow for a single comma with something like `r'(\d+,)?\d+ '`.

Comment: Well my code is already successful at recognizing commas and the surrounding numbers. What I'm asking is for a different way (or an additional way) to capture the weight values that are less than 1,000 and therefore have no commas.

Comment: What I wrote in my previous comment says "either a stream of digits, or a stream of digits with a single comma inside it". Is that not what you need?

Comment: Oh oh ohhhhh! My mistake. I'll give that a try. But won't it also recognize numbers like the "5" in the subject line?

Comment: Hmm not sure why but that printed out: `Weight: 1,1,30,6,22,14,1,5,10,`

Comment: If all the weights before "lbs" are whole numbers, you can reject any that have a period in them and filter out the non-weight values.

Comment: Yes, it will recognise numbers like "5". That's why I was missing the `'lbs'` part:) In general, you probably need something like `r'(\d+,)?\d+ lbs'`, then discard the last 4 characters. And I'd use `' '.join(...)` for printing, so that you can distinguish `1,4 2` from `1,42`.

Comment: `r'(\d+,)*\d+ lbs'` is probably your best bet. That's going to give you an arbitrary number of `,`'s.

Comment: @martineau that sounds like it could work......is the RegEx for that simple enough? Sorry, I'm not an expert with RegEx

Comment: @AndrasDeak I tried `r'(\d+,)?\d+ lbs` and it seems to only capture the numbers *before* the commas but not after. That is a simple enough fix right?

Comment: @cwallenpoole that RegEx does the same as the others :( it just prints the numbers before the commas....excluding the numbers after the commas and the numbers with no commas at all

Comment: How about this: `\s([\d,]+)\s*lb` It captures all digits and commas preceded by a space and followed by some number of spaces followed by `lb` https://regex101.com/r/Tpy0So/1

Comment: @theprowler the issue seems to be how `findall` works. If you use the same pattern with `re.finditer` and iterate through the matches, you'll see that it finds each part as expected.

Comment: @theprowler: I are not a RegExpert either. Seems like you could use one to get all numbers and then manually reject any matches that contained periods. However there's probably a regular expression way to do it (via negative lookaheads or something like that).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That worked! I can't believe it but it did. It captured all the weights, those in the 100's and 1000's. I just have two questions: 1) what if there are no spaces preceding the value? Like what if it is the beginning of the line, will it still work? Such as: `4,000 lbs of fish for-`... And 2) what if there is no space between the end of the value and 'lbs' will it still work? Such as: ` 4,000lbs' ...?

Comment: Also, to everyone who responded on this page, thank you all so much. I can't thank you guys enough for even offering to help a noob like me, I really do appreciate it all.

Comment: Good observation about the beginning of a line.  The `*` matches zero or more spaces, so `40000lbs` is accepted.  Here's an updated regex `(?<!\.)([\d,]+)\s*lb`  https://regex101.com/r/Tpy0So/2

Comment: Hmm, it's not printing now...it's now saying for my `print` line: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, _sre.SRE_match found` This can't be a RegEx issue but I don't know why changing the RegEx would mess this up....I'll do some googling

Comment: Have a try with [`[\d,.]+\b(?=\s*lbs)`](https://regex101.com/r/5OlFz9/1)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways, one being

```
\d[\d,]{2,} lbs
```

This require a digit, followed by digits, commas a space and lbs literally. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WFx3Vo/3).

---

In full `Python`:

```
import re

email = """
2) From: Claire Fitz-Gerald 
   Date: 9/5/2014 9:52 AM
   Subject: NEFS 5 Available Fish

   All,
   NEFS 5 has the following fish available for lease/trade:

     GB EAST cod: 954 lbs @ $0.83
     GB EAST cod: 1,046 lbs to trade for 1,830 lbs GB WEST cod
     GB blackback: 30,000 lbs @ $0.07
     GOM blackback: 800 lbs @ $0.03
     white hake: 6,322 lbs @ $0.13
     pollock: 22,000 lbs @ $0.015
     redfish: 14,000 lbs @ $0.015
     GB yt: 1,873 lbs @ $1.13
     GB yt: 5,127 lbs to trade for 10,254 lbs SNE yt
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(\d[\d,]{2,}) lbs')
weights = rx.findall(email)
print(weights)
```

See it [**working on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/DR0GVd).

Comment: But the thing is I *want* the values below `1000`. My current RegEx can capture all the values above `1000` but it's the values without commas that are messing me up